# Como comparar duas Strings em haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
buscaLivroNome :: Livro -> Nome -> String
buscaLivroNome [] _ = "Nao Encontrado"
buscaLivroNome ((codigo,nome1,preco, autor, ano):resto) nome2 | nome1 == nome2 = "Livro Encontrado" | otherwise = buscaLivroNome resto nome2
```

Preciso comparar se as strings `nome1` e `nome2` são iguais, mas está retornando esse erro:

> Exception: Prelude.read: no parse

Comment: [Compare strings in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819620/compare-strings-in-haskell)

Comment: Faltam informações na sua pergunta, como o tipo completo do `Livro` e do `Nome`, além disso, a função `read` não está sendo chamada em nenhum lugar do seu código.